# Data cross matching with mysql two tables, value display in table using PHP mySql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having some trouble with php and mysql, I am even not sure how to properly ask the question, it seems very complex. Still if anyone can help me, i will be very thankful.

i have two tables 
(allunit.sql)

```
id - unit_name
12       -   MIS
14       -   MIT
15       - ENG
```

when someone click enroll button from browser (unit_id) will store in enrollment table. if some one enroll into the unit, button will show (Already Enrolled), not not it will show "Enroll"
enrollment.sql

```
enroll_id - unit_id
1         - 12
2         - 14
```

I am using this query

```
$unit = SELECT * FROM allunit;

$enroll = SELECT * FROM enrollment;

$row_enroll = mysqli_fetch_assoc($enroll);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($unit)) {
    if($row['id']==$row_enroll['unit_id']){
        $button = 'Already enrolled';
    }else{
        $button = 'Enroll';
    }
?>

<tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['unit_name']; ?></td>

           <td><?php echo $button; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

if i add one unit button changes to "already Enrolled" for that unit, but if i add more than one, still only one button changes. other stays same "enroll".

I know my question is reallty messy, hope you will understand. Badly need help. Thank you

Comment: Did you make a connection to the database?

Comment: Yes database is fine, i actually made the post very short, as it was very complex to me to explain, but it change for one row only, even though i have values for multiple row, i know the way i am doing it will give one row, but I don't know hoe to feach for multiple rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to tell the database to run your query, it is not enough to place a query in a text string. This is done, in this case using the `query()` method.

Second, as you want to process the Enrolments once for each of the Units, it would be useful to unload at least the Enrolment into an array so it is easily reusable

```
// assuming you have a connection and its in $con

$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM allunit';
$units   = $con->query($sql);

$sql    = 'SELECT unit_id FROM enrollment';
$res2   = $con->query($sql);
// make an array of just the enrolment id's as that all you need
// so we can use in_array() later to do the test for are you already enrolled
$enrols = [];
while ($row = $res2->fetch_assoc()){
    $enrols[] = $row['unit_id'];
}

while ($unit = $units->fetch_assoc() ) {
    if ( in_array($unit['id'], $enrols) ) {
        $button = 'Already enrolled';
    }else{
        $button = 'Enroll';
    }

?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $unit['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $unit['unit_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $button; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
} // endwhile
?>
```

Comment: WOW it worked, i was not familiar with  $enroll[] and in _array option. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I see in your code:

1. `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` is called on a MySQL result, not a query. You need to call `mysqli_query()` first. You can see an example in the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php
2. When you get a result, such as `$row_enroll`, it's a collection of rows, so you can't use it with a column directly, i.e. `$row_enroll['unit_id']` won't give you anything.

Finally, it doesn't appear that a comparison between two separate datasets like this is going to work well for you, at least with the current code. Consider using [`JOIN`s](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to return just one dataset.